# Standard library Priority Queue push method

Tags: algorithm, go, priority-queue

The code snippet below is the library implementation of the push methods for a priority queue. I am wondering why the line with the code `a = a[0 : n+1]` does not throw an out of bounds errors.

```
 func (pq *PriorityQueue) Push(x interface{}) {
    // Push and Pop use pointer receivers because they modify the slice's length,
    // not just its contents.
    // To simplify indexing expressions in these methods, we save a copy of the
    // slice object. We could instead write (*pq)[i].
    a := *pq
    n := len(a)
    a = a[0 : n+1]
    item := x.(*Item)
    item.index = n
    a[n] = item
    *pq = a
}
```

Answer (score 3):

a slice is not an array; it is a view onto an existing array.  The slice in question is backed by an array larger than itself.  When you define a slice of an existing slice, you're actually slicing the underlying array, but the indexes referenced are relative to the source slice.

That's a mouthful.  Let's prove this in the following way:  we'll create a slice of zero length, but we'll force the underlying array to be larger.  When creating a slice with `make`, the third parameter will set the size of the underlying array.  The expression `make([]int, 0, 2)` will allocate an array of size 2, but it evaluates to a size-zero slice.

```
package main

import ("fmt")

func main() {
    // create a zero-width slice over an initial array of size 2
    a := make([]int, 0, 2)
    fmt.Println(a)

    // expand the slice.  Since we're not beyond the size of the initial
    // array, this isn't out of bounds.
    a = a[0:len(a)+1]

    a[0] = 1
    fmt.Println(a)
    fmt.Println(a[0:len(a)+1])
}
```

[see here](http://play.golang.org/p/YygcfTRQl5).  You can use the `cap` keyword to reference the size of the array that backs a given slice.

The specific code that you asked about loops over `cap(pq)` in the calling context (container/heap/example_test.go line 90).  If you modify the code at the call site and attempt to push another item into the queue, it will panic like you expect.  I ... probably wouldn't suggest writing code like this.  Although the code in the standard library executes, I would be very sour if I found that in my codebase.  It's generally safer to use the `append` keyword.

Answer (score 2):

Because it works in a *specific* example program. Here are the important parts from the original/full [example source](http://golang.org/pkg/container/heap/#example_))

```
const nItem = 10
```

and

```
pq := make(PriorityQueue, 0, nItem)
```

and

```
for i := 0; i < cap(pq); i++ {
        item := &Item{
                value:    values[i],
                priority: priorities[i],
        }
        heap.Push(&pq, item)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it an example from [container/heap](http://golang.org/pkg/container/heap/#example_)? If yes, then it doesn't throws an exception because capacity is big enough (see how the `Push` method is used). If you change the example to `Push` more items then the capacity, then it'll throw.